# Using Emailjs-imap-client with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I got webpack running and would like to use emailjs-imap-client.
Sadly I cannot get it to work ...
I always get the following errors:

```
[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "emailjs-imap-client-imap"
[WDS] Hot Module Replacement enabled.
[WDS] Errors while compiling.
./~/emailjs-imap-client/src/emailjs-imap-client.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'emailjs-imap-client-imap' in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/src
resolve module emailjs-imap-client-imap in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/src
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-client-imap in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-client-imap in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-client-imap in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap doesn't exist (module as directory)
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client-imap]
 @ ./~/emailjs-imap-client/src/emailjs-imap-client.js 5:8-140
./~/emailjs-imap-client/~/emailjs-imap-handler/src/emailjs-imap-parser.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'emailjs-imap-formal-syntax' in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/src
resolve module emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/src
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist (module as directory)
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
 @ ./~/emailjs-imap-client/~/emailjs-imap-handler/src/emailjs-imap-parser.js 25:8-55
./~/emailjs-imap-client/~/emailjs-imap-handler/src/emailjs-imap-compiler.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'emailjs-imap-formal-syntax' in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/src
resolve module emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/src
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist (module as directory)
  looking for modules in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules
    resolve 'file' emailjs-imap-formal-syntax in /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules
      resolve file
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js doesn't exist
        /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json doesn't exist
    /home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax doesn't exist (module as directory)
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.webpack.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.web.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.json]
[/home/yatekii/Projects/Yatekii.github.io/node_modules/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax]
 @ ./~/emailjs-imap-client/~/emailjs-imap-handler/src/emailjs-imap-compiler.js 25:8-55
```

This looks very strange to me because it is looking for the modules at awkward places. My npm modules are in /home/yatekii/Yatekii.github.io/react-hot-boilerplate/node_modules/.
The module emailjs-imap-formal-syntax for example is here: ./node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/src/emailjs-imap-formal-syntax.js

How can I get node/webpack to find the modules? :S

I tried this in my webpack-config:

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: 'emailjs-imap-client',
        loader: "imports?define=>false"
      },
      {
        test: 'emailjs-imap-client-imap',
        loader: 'imports?define=>false',
        include: 'emailjs-imap-client/src/emailjs-imap-client-imap.js')
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
      },
    ]
  }
};
```

I get the error just when I do:

```
var ImapClient = require('emailjs-imap-client');
var client = new ImapClient('mail.yatekii.ch', 143, {
        auth: {
                user: 'yatekii@yatekii.ch',
                pass: 'VERYSECRET'
        }
    }
)
```

Is anyone able to help me? Thanks a ton!
Peace Yatekii

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at my example of using emailjs modules + webpack:

https://github.com/Axel186/emailjs-and-webpack-example

There you can find working client example that uses emailjs-imap-client.

anyway, here is the part of webpack config file:

```
  ...
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|forge\.js)/,
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      query: {
        compact: true,
        presets: ['es2015']
      }
    }]
  },
  alias: {
    forge: 'forge.js'
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      // path.resolve('./src/app'),
      path.resolve('./src/'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules/emailjs-imap-client/src/'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules/emailjs-imap-handler/src/'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules/emailjs-tcp-socket/src/'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules/emailjs-smtp-client/src/'),
      path.resolve('./node_modules/emailjs-stringencoding/src/'),
    ]
  },
  ...
```